# Magento invaild user name and password not showing

Tags: magento-1.9

Magento **invaild user name and password** not showing.

> I open in Login page
>   Enter Invalid username and password it redirect
>   to previous page but not logged in  if i click login again it redirect
>   to login page it shows error

what is the problem on it

Answer (score 0):

Often this happens when you have a issue with your sessions. 
Are you storing it in DB or Files.. 
Try to clean your sessions folder. and be sure there is no disk space issue!